# How to deploy Gatsby 5 React app to Docker container using AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, gatsby, amazon-ecs

My current Dockerfile is:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:14.18.0-buster

# Create app directory
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true
RUN npm install -g gatsby-cli

WORKDIR /app

# Install app dependencies
# RUN npm -g install serve
RUN yarn global add gatsby-cli

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --arch=amd64 --platform=linuxmusl sharp

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Build static files
#RUN SHARP_IGNORE_GLOBAL_LIBVIPS=1 yarn add --arch=arm64 --platform=linux sharp

RUN yarn run build

# serve on port 8090
CMD ["gatsby", "serve", "--verbose", "--prefix-paths", "-p", "8090", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

After deploying this, the Docker container is not starting in ECS, keeps failing the deployment with no error.

Need to successfully release the Gatsby version 5 app to AWS ECS.

Comment: If you run the same docker image locally, does it work? If not, you need to focus on getting that working first before attempting to deploy to AWS. If it does work locally, then you need to provide us with much more information about how you are deploying to ECS before we can help you. For example including the ECS task definition in your question would be a good start.